# How can I make my terminal's command prompt shorter to increase line realestate?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I would like to make my terminal's command prompt shorter. Currently I am using Python 's `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` so that is causing lots of extra text to be displayed in my command prompt. I need to shorten that up to the bare minimum so I'd like to take this:

```
(pytutorial)sez@sez-laptop:~/.virtualenvs/nettuts/firstblog$
```

and ideally turn it into

```
(pyt)sez:~/.virtualenvs/nettuts/firstblog$
```

or maybe something shorter perhaps. Right now I am using Gnome Terminal 2 & bash.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your prompt can be set utilizing the PS1 envvar.  For example to have a minimalist command prompt of '$" simply set PS1='$' in your .bashrc.  [Here are some good examples of setting a customized prompt](http://maketecheasier.com/8-useful-and-interesting-bash-prompts/2009/09/04)

Answer (score 7):

I guess `\u:\w\$` is what you need, where `\u` is your username and `\w` is the current working directory (`\W` is shorter).
Modify your `~/.bashrc` to change the prompt.

Comment: +1 ... in the middle of typing pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `.bashrc` and change the `PS1` definition. See your own `/etc/bashrc` for an example, or see bash documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Simply type in your terminal nano .bash_profile.
Copy:

```
export PS1="\u@\h\w: "
```

Save.

Answer (score 3):

We use a consistent header across all our machines, that has the full current working directory on the line (along with hostname and user), then a line break with just the current directory name and the prompt itself.

That way, you still get plenty of width and there is a clear distinction between different lines.

Its also coloured :)

```
export PS1="\e[0;35m[\u@\e[0;33s\h\e[0;35m \w] \e[m \n[\W]\$ "
```

Eg. Which would output

```
[myuser@myserver /home/myuser]
[myuser]$
```

Save the line in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile` to make it persistent.

Answer (score 2):

I like to have my prompt in a separate line so I don't miss the info and I always have the whole line to type:

```
PS1=\\u@\\h\ \\w\\n\\$\
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the '$WORKON_HOME/postactivate':

```
case $(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV") in
    pytutorial) VENV="pyt";;
    *) VENV="$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV")";;
esac
PS1="($VENV)$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
```

Inside the '$HOME/.bashrc':

```
PS1="\u:\w\$ "
```

This should produce the exact output you described. Of course there are different options. I highly recommend https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt, for more info on this topic.

The 'post_activate' file runs during virtualenv startup. The `case` statement allows you to replace a name with another.

Other considerations:

I personally do `PS1=$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1` in '$WORKON_HOME/postactivate' and use `$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV")` inside my `PS1`.